# Smoothing a minimum function under constraints

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, statistics, optimization

Let $F$ and $G$ be two cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) on the real line. I am interested in the function

$$Q(x,y)=\min \{F(x),G(y)\}. $$

$Q$ is a CDF on $\mathbb R^2$, with marginals $F$ and $G$. But it is not smooth. I am looking for a way to approximate $Q$ by a smooth function $Q_\epsilon$ $(\epsilon >0)$ such that $Q_\epsilon \rightarrow Q$ pointwise when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

$Q_\epsilon$ needs to be a CDF on $\mathbb R^2$, have marginals $F$ and $G$, and admit a density $q_\epsilon$ everywhere. There is an extra condition: if $F,G$ are CDF of standard Gaussians (mean $0$, variance $1$), $Q_\epsilon$ must be the CDF of a bi-normal with mean $0$ and covariance

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4+\epsilon^{4}}}{2} \\
-\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4+\epsilon^{4}}}{2} & 1 
\end{array}\right]$$

Any suggestion on how to smooth that minimum such that those constraints are satisfied ? The usual soft-minimums used in machine learning seem to not work. Maybe a convolution ?

Comment: How can you do that with allowing for some approximation error? If the actual CDF has atoms 9 (i.e., where it is non-smooth), there is no density there, and the CDF can not be exactly duplicated with a continuous CDF.If me assessment is not correct, please better explain your scenario..

Comment: The setting is very clear. For $\epsilon >0$, $Q_\epsilon$ is any CDF that satisfies the constraints. When $\epsilon$ goes to 0, the limit must be $Q$ a-e.

Comment: it may be clear to you. I don't see how it's possible, hence my question.